# How to get directions to my default location in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

When I go to Google Maps, it shows my default location. Often I then search/find a location/address and then want to get Directions from my default location, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do that. When I click on directions, it wants me to type an address. If I start typing the addr of my default location, it doesn't autocomplete or even list it among the choices until I've typed most of it.

I thought "it" (Google Maps or more likely my browser) used to remember the places I'd typed in for the originating address, which enabled me to choose from previous entries in a drop down. But that seemed to disappear once Maps started doing instant search on what I'm typing in the address field.

Ideally I'd like to have a few locations (e.g. home, work) and choose them as the starting point for directions unless I wait to specifically type in an address. But I don't see anything like this.

Comment: If you have web history on (you must be signed on to a google account), you'll suggestions with auto complete from your search history.

Comment: @Joel H, I'm pretty much always signed in to google in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In google maps click "My places" then assign "home" address. Next time you're searching for directions you can simply begin typing "home" into one of the direction fields and it will load your home address. Presumably this works with your "work" location as well.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to his current location, which might or might not be his home.

Comment: @Chris: you're right. In the desktop Maps, Under My Places, that's marked as a "new" feature and exactly what I was looking for. Nice to see they are still improving the app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your Web History <strike>for Maps</strike> is enabled.
Go to the settings and check.

Here are my full steps.

1. Go to google.com
2. Sign in at the top right hand corner
3. You will redirected to google.com after signing in
4. Click the arrow with your name again in the right hand corner
5. Click Account Settings
6. Select Web History
7. Click on maps

Alternatively you can just go https://www.google.com/history/?hl=en if you already signed in.

Now check if the History is paused or not

[image: Web History in Enabled]

You should be able to see something similar to the following under Maps Web History.

[image: Some bars I have searched]

Now if you have a default location fixed into your account, then pointing your browser to http://maps.google.com/ should set you to your default location. To auto-complete previous locations, just start typing the first few letters and it will show up.

[image: Auto-complete for Velvet Club with one letter]

[image: Auto-complete for Velvet Club with two letters]

Also on the opening Maps page, there is an arrow that leads to recent searches.

[image: Recent Searches on Maps]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which setting you mean.
I do notice this now in Google maps: "New! My Places" Maybe I need to set addresses here to have them remembered when I'm getting directions.

Comment: I went to the Global Preferences which has a "Location" field. It says the following. But adding this didn't seem to help when I then tried to get directions to a location.

`Use as the default location in Google Maps, customized search results, and other Google products:

This location is saved on this computer. Learn more`

Comment: @Cin You want [Account Settings](https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/ManageAccount) not Global Preferences

Comment: Your updated instructions help. When I went to Web History (under Try something new), I had to authorize enabling it. There was nothing particular under Maps at that time. I did some searches and I do see now that it remembers past addresses I used. That is helpful (though I seem to recall Firefox did that automatically before Google went to Instant Search which bypasses that) but it's not exactly what I asked for.