# How do I get directions from/to my saved locations?

Tags: google-maps

When I find an address in Google Maps, it helpfully shows "4 min drive - work" under the address.
When I click on the note, I get the directions from work.
How, I also have `home` saved in Google Maps - how do I get the directions from/to there?

When I type `home` (or `Home`) in the `Source` input, Google Maps displays the directions from a random place on the map with the word "home" in it, not from my saved home location (contrary to what is promised in [the answers to another question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15985/how-to-get-directions-to-my-default-location-in-google-maps)).

PS. Also, the search suggestions have *nothing* to do with my previous searches; e.g., no matter how many times I search for "abcd, NY, NY" when I start to type "ab.." the top suggestions are "abzz, BO, CO" &c

Comment: @pnuts: why do I have to type in an address which I told google maps to save?

Comment: @pnuts: yes, but finding the home icon requires zooming far out.

Comment: @pnuts: yes, they do look different...

Comment: @pnuts: oooookay.... so, what do I do? clear the google cookies?

Comment: @pnuts: I don't have the "google earth" dir and no "*.kml" files on my disk, but google maps does show my places - it just does not complete on them.